# ¿Son equivalentes "Así + subjuntivo" y "esperar que +subjuntivo"?

Tags: gramática, subjuntivo

> Mario olvidó comprar los ingredientes para el pozole del mercado. **Así regrese** del trabajo para que pueda volver a decírselo.

Me gustaría saber si es similar a la frase:

> Mario olvidó comprar los ingredientes para el pozole del mercado. **Espero que regrese** del trabajo para que pueda volver a decírselo.

Comment: [1) olividar **de** hace algo; 2) los ingredientes en el mercado para el pozole]

Answer (score 1):

*Así* en este caso equivale a *ojalá* (definición nº 11 de *[así](https://dle.rae.es/?id=3zT41MT)* en el DLE). Igual que *ojalá*, se utiliza seguido de un verbo en subjuntivo.

> *Así regrese* = *ojalá regrese*,

es decir, *espero/deseo que regrese*.

No es un uso de la palabra que me resulte familiar. Quizá otros miembros del foro puedan decirme si *así* se usa de esta manera en sus países o regiones de origen.

Comment: En España lo he oído de forma algo cómica: _Así venga un huracán y te despeine_.

Answer (score 0):

"*Así + subjetivo*" se suele utilizar como "*Ojalá + subjetivo*". Sin embargo, mientras "ojalá", normalmente, se refriere más a algo positivo, "así" es más bien referido hacia algo negativo.