# ¿Cuál es el significado de la construcción "¡cómo + imperfecto!"?

Tags: gramática, pretérito-imperfecto

> ¡Qué niño! ¡**Cómo comía**! ¡Así se le hayan indigestado los pasteles!

¿La expresión “cómo + imperfecto” significa "la manera en que comía el niño"?

Comment: Expresa sorpresa ante la capacidad de comer del niño.

Comment: ¿Debe ser en el imperfecto? ¿Se puede ser también en el pretérito?

Comment: En cualquier tiempo de verbo: *¡Cómo come! ¡Cómo comió! ¡Cómo está comiendo! ¡Cómo va a comer!*, etc.

Comment: @Gustavson perfecto! Si pudieras moverlo a respuesta...

Comment: @fedorqui Seguramente no escribí una respuesta porque tendría que haberme referido al contexto y la exclamación "¡Así se le hayan indigestado los pasteles!" no es utilizada en Argentina. Es importante el contexto porque si en vez de indigestión hablara de tener las manos o la boca sucias de comida, "cómo" estaría haciendo alusión a los modales en la mesa y no a la cantidad de comida.

Comment: @Gustavson entiendo. En España no en exceso, pero sí de vez en cuando (en general [de forma humorística](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/31874/son-equivalentes-as%C3%AD-subjuntivo-y-esperar-que-subjuntivo/31880#comment58820_31880). A ver si Hausmeister33 puede clarificar la pregunta aportando más contexto.

Answer (score 3):

La traducción más parecida de esa expresión sería el equivalente en inglés "what a way to eat".

No necesariamente denota sorpresa, sino énfasis en cuanto a la manera en que algo se llevaba a cabo. En este contexto, es correcto el tiempo pretérito. Porque se refiere al relato de una acción que sucedió en el pasado.

Como por ejemplo, cuando estás narrando la forma en que alguien ganó una pelea, puedes hacer uso de la expresión, "Pero viste sus rodillas?, cómo las usaba sobre la cara del oponente!"

Significa que haces un especial énfasis en la manera en que el peleador estaba levantando alto sus rodillas para castigar al oponente en la cara". Repito nuevamente, no necesariamente en tono de sorpresa, sino haciendo énfasis en la forma particular en la que sacó ventaja de la situación. Es mas bien enfatizar algo no usual. Puede ser que no te haya sorprendido, pero no lo has visto muy frecuentemente.