# Así + pretérito imperfecto de subjuntivo vs así + pretérito perfecto de subjuntivo

Tags: gramática

¡Vaya mujer! ¡Así le hayan dicho lo que se merece!

En este caso “así” significa “ojala”, ¿verdad?

Arturo se ha comido todos los bombones. —Así le sienten mal.

Aquí está frase es similar a la primera, ¿no?
¿Cuál es la diferencia?

¡Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Esta pregunta se respondería como la respondió @pablodf76 [aquí](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/31874/as%C3%AD-subjuntivo-vs-esperar-que-subjuntivo).

El segundo ejemplo podría ser ambiguo puesto que "así" podría tener el sentido concesivo que se le atribuye en la [acepción (7)](https://dle.rae.es/?id=3zT41MT) del DLE:

> conj. Aunque, por más que. U. para introducir oraciones en subjuntivo.
>   *Lo encontraré, así tenga que registrar toda la casa.*

Si a Arturo siempre le caen mal los bombones, podemos tener esta conversación:

(A) Arturo se ha comido todos los bombones.

(B) Así le sienten mal. (= Los ha comido aunque le sienten mal.)